# Angular.js in Salesforce not loaded in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, salesforce

I have deploy AngualrJs and Visualforce application in SFDC,  Its working fine in IE10 , IE11 , Chrome , Mozilla but its not loaded in IE9. I have tried this

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"  controller="CartController">
    <!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  lang="en-US" data-ng-app="diageoApp" id="ng-app" data-ng-controller="masterCtrl"> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  
    <html lang="en-US" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  ng-app="diageoApp" id="ng-app" ng-controller="masterCtrl" >
        <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie
It has info about IE8 issues that might be useful to you.

Comment: I have checked it , but not helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that those Angular properties in your `html` tag aren't making it into the Visualforce page.  One easy workaround is to setup Angular on something in the body, like:

```
<div ng-app="ngApp">
```

For a working example check out: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/07/building-salesforce1-apps-visualforce-angularjs-bootstrap.html